# Использовать ли рефлексию при реализации своего DI

Tags: java, рефлексия, аннотации, di

Есть идея написать свой DI через аннотации*. Я уже решился писать реализацию c помощью рефлексии, но слышал что она очень медленная.
Как лучше поступить?

*- аннотация должна внедрять одну зависимость в объект.

Например:

```
public class A {
    public void doSomething() {}
}

public class B {
    @Inject(A.class)
    private A a;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Порекомендую, если это не в учебных целях, не писать свой DI.

Answer (score 3):

В данной задаче скорость работы рефлексии вас волновать не должна. Если всё, что делает ваш DI, это внедрение зависимостей в создаваемые бины, то рефлексия будет использована один раз за всё время жизни бина - при его создании. Несмотря на то, что манипуляции с объектами через рефлексию могут быть в 20 раз медленнее прямых манипуляций, вы не заметите этой разницы, пока не станете создавать по несколько десятков тысяч объектов с зависимостями.

Вместо беспокойства о производительности рефлексии, в первую очередь стоит задуматься о целесообразности написания собственного DI при живых Spring, Guice и Dagger. Если это делается не в учебных целях, стоит пользоваться существующими, проверенными временем решениями.